# Is there any way apart from the weak/strong dance to use an instance variable in a block?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, instance-variables, weak-references

In Objective-C, you may want to use an instance variable inside a block, and store that block in the object itself. If you do that, you run into quite a hassle to make sure that you don't create a circular dependency, and to silence all compiler warnings:

```
@implementation TestBlock {
    int someVariable;
    void (^someBlock)();
}

- (void) createBlock
{
    // ideally I would like to use:
    someBlock = ^{
        someVariable++;
    };

    // but in reality I need to use:
    TestBlock * __weak weakSelf = self;
    someBlock = ^{
        TestBlock *strongSelf = weakSelf;
        strongSelf->someVariable++;
    };
}

@end
```

If `weakSelf` is used, instead of `strongSelf`, then you'll get the error:

> Dereferencing a __weak pointer is not allowed

If you use `self` directly, then a retain cycle is created.

I know the background of why this is needed, but is there really no easier way to use an instance variable inside a block? Any practical approaches that you have used to make this shorter and more readable?

Comment: You have no other option to access the ivar directly. But you do have the option to use a property around the ivar. Then you can access the property using `wealSelf`.

Comment: If you have to access the ivar, you can use the "@weakify" and "@strongify" macros <http://holko.pl/2015/05/31/weakify-strongify/>, which makes it a little more readable.

Comment: The crux is to avoid blocks as ivars. For example, you may redesign your class so that it may have methods which accept a block as parameter.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner I didn't know about the weakify-strongify macros that you mention, and it is an interesting idea that I will certainly try out. At the very least it makes it concise and clearer what is going on.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper to have a block as a direct instance variable like I show in the example is indeed rare. But it very common to have an iVar with an object of another class, that holds a block that you supplied to it. That would constitute the exact same problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a `property` for your ivar you can reference that property directly on a `weak` reference (although it is effectively a method call).  If you want to access the instance variable directly then you have to do the `weak`/`strong` dance that you have in your posted code.

I realize that it's an Objective-C question, but it's worth noting this is the problem that [capture lists](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID57) in Swift solve.

Comment: Of course, the property access when you just want to increment an int is rather a pain in the rear: `[self setSomeVariable:[self someVariable] + 1];`

Comment: It's valid Objective-C property syntax to write `self.someVariable = self.someVariable + 1;`

Comment: It's even valid syntax to write `self.someVariable++`. But to the question's premise, it is incredibly rare that creating an ivar directly is a good idea. It is even less common that accessing it with `->` is a good idea. Properties are the correct way to implement all of this. (Though properties still require a bit of strong/weak dancing in most cases. As CouchDeveloper suggests, it's often best to try to design around needing it if you can.)

Comment: It's true, that is certainly the best approach. There are places where you don't have a choice but to do the `strong`/`weak` dance, though (like `NSNotificationCenter` block based API).

Comment: Making it a property will reduce the issue in half (you'll still need the weak part of it). But I really don't like using properties for purely technical reasons like this. Properties are great for public variables of the class, but for its private data, I don't see a real conceptual reason for using them. For that I feel it is clearer, more straightforward, and also more efficient to use iVars.

Comment: I generally feel the same way you do with respect to using iVars for internal implementation.  However, when it comes to referencing inside blocks, it's best to use the clearest method to avoid retain cycles, and that method is using properties.  I've given up that fight.  Clarity and debug-ability of code is far more important than purity.

Comment: In terms of efficiency, you can always refer to the iVar backing the property directly in code that is not part of a block.